# Sanitizing an ASP.NET web site project for open source sharing purposes?

Tags: asp.net, open-source, webmatrix

I am writing an article on creating a **WebMatrix 3/ASP.NET** web site that lives in the **Azure** cloud.  I want to make sure that I have removed all information that needs to be kept private to my account from the project I am sharing.  So far I have replaced my public and private **ReCAPTCHA** keys with with string constants.  An example of a piece of information I am concerned about is the **PublicKeyToken** field in the **Web.config** file.  Do I need to replace the key value in that file too?  If so, how does the user rebuild/replace the value easily for their own purposes?

What other pieces of information or DLLs, etc. do I need to clean up before safely sharing the entire project in a compressed folder?  (If there a another known way to safely share a WebMatrix 3/ASP.NET project please let me know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with hiding your ReCAPTCHA keys - a lot of people miss this step, and you want to make sure not to share these keys.  The PublicKeyToken field in web.config is nothing to worry about.  This is simply a hash of a public key that matches up to a private key used to sign assemblies used in your application - that key is likely the same across anyone who is using .NET, and is not something you should be concerned about :)

Other bits of information you should make sure not to share:

- Connection strings
- Any Azure *.publishSettings file ( shouldn't be in your site, but I would make sure )
- Any application keys used for auth (twitter, facebook, etc)

In terms of how to share the site - why not upload it to CodePlex or GitHub?  WebMatrix 3 has a bunch of built in goodies for working with Git, so that's probably the easiest way to share the code:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-use-git-in-webmatrix

Please make sure to share the site with us on twitter @webmatrix after you finish it!

Happy Coding :)